# How do I switch between panels using a CardLayout?

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, layout-manager, cardlayout

I have made a `parentPanel` that has a `CardLayout` on it, and under this I've made 4 more `JPanel` containers.

On the left side I have 4 buttons that when I press `"Forside"` (button) I want to switch to the panel on the card layout (`Forside`) and so on...

I've tried different youtube tutorials and tried to look on here without any success.
Everything I have tried has ended up with a `NullPointerException`

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    int xx, xy;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Main frame = new Main();
                    frame.setUndecorated(true); // Hides the jframe top bar
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Main() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 735, 506);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBackground(new Color(102, 102, 102));
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JPanel panelLeft = new JPanel();
        panelLeft.setBackground(new Color(51, 51, 51));
        panelLeft.setForeground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        panelLeft.setBounds(0, 54, 150, 459);
        contentPane.add(panelLeft);
        panelLeft.setLayout(null);

        JButton btnForside = new JButton("Forside");
        btnForside.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            }
        });
        btnForside.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        btnForside.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        btnForside.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 17));
        btnForside.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("/Images/icons8_Home_32px_1.png")));
        btnForside.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btnForside.setBorderPainted(false);
        btnForside.setBorder(null);
        btnForside.setBounds(16, 60, 112, 30);
        panelLeft.add(btnForside);

        JButton btnDagbog = new JButton("Dagbog");
        btnDagbog.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });
        btnDagbog.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        btnDagbog.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btnDagbog.setBorderPainted(false);
        btnDagbog.setBorder(null);
        btnDagbog.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 17));
        btnDagbog.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        btnDagbog.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("/Images/icons8_Book_32px.png")));
        btnDagbog.setBounds(16, 116, 112, 30);
        panelLeft.add(btnDagbog);

        JButton btnAftaler = new JButton("Aftaler");
        btnAftaler.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        btnAftaler.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        btnAftaler.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btnAftaler.setBorderPainted(false);
        btnAftaler.setBorder(null);
        btnAftaler.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        btnAftaler.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 17));
        btnAftaler.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("/Images/icons8_Planner_32px.png")));
        btnAftaler.setBounds(16, 173, 112, 30);
        panelLeft.add(btnAftaler);

        JButton btnKontakt = new JButton("Kontakt");
        btnKontakt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        btnKontakt.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        btnKontakt.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btnKontakt.setBorder(null);
        btnKontakt.setBorderPainted(false);
        btnKontakt.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 17));
        btnKontakt.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        btnKontakt.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("/Images/icons8_Phone_32px.png")));
        btnKontakt.setBounds(16, 231, 112, 30);
        panelLeft.add(btnKontakt);

        JPanel panelTop = new JPanel();
        panelTop.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
                int x = arg0.getXOnScreen(); // makes uggerhøj picture dragable
                int y = arg0.getYOnScreen(); // makes uggerhøj picture dragable
                Main.this.setLocation(x - xx, y - xy);  // makes uggerhøj picture dragable
            }
        });
        panelTop.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                 xx = e.getX(); // makes uggerhøj picture dragable
                 xy = e.getY(); // makes uggerhøj picture dragable
            }
        });
        panelTop.setBackground(new Color(51, 51, 51));
        panelTop.setBounds(0, 0, 737, 60);
        contentPane.add(panelTop);
        panelTop.setLayout(null);

        JButton btnX = new JButton("X");
        btnX.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        btnX.setRolloverIcon(null);
        btnX.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 18));
        btnX.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        btnX.setFocusPainted(false);
        btnX.setBorderPainted(false);
        btnX.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        btnX.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btnX.setForeground(SystemColor.activeCaption);
        btnX.setBorder(null);
        btnX.setBounds(615, 13, 97, 25);
        panelTop.add(btnX);

        JPanel parentPanel = new JPanel();
        parentPanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        parentPanel.setBounds(148, 54, 569, 405);
        contentPane.add(parentPanel);
        parentPanel.setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));

        JPanel Forside = new JPanel();
        parentPanel.add(Forside, "name_1472174211097300");
        Forside.setFocusable(false);

        JButton btnTest = new JButton("test");
        Forside.add(btnTest);

        JPanel Dagbog = new JPanel();
        parentPanel.add(Dagbog, "name_1472176236196000");

        JLabel lblTest = new JLabel("dagbog");
        Dagbog.add(lblTest);


        JPanel Aftaler = new JPanel();
        parentPanel.add(Aftaler, "name_1472177885026100");

        JPanel Kontakt = new JPanel();
        parentPanel.add(Kontakt, "name_1472179607862700");
    }
}
```

I'd just want it so the right buttons leads to the right cards.

Comment: 1) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form. 2) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556) 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  ..

Comment: .. As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 4) *"Everything I have tried has ended up with a `NullPointerException`"* Hopefully by the time you have carefully read the Q&As related to stack traces and NPE's this next comment will mkae perfect sense. **Always copy/paste error and exception output!**

Comment: When trying to run your code I get a NullPointerException at this line:
    btnForside.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("/Images/icons8_Home_32px_1.png"))); Do you also get the NPE here? If so the problem is that the images are not where they should be

Comment: .. 5) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Yes, complete with `import` statements so we can ensure the stack trace here is the equivalent of the stack trace there. Limit it to 2 panels, rather than 4. 6) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). E.G. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) hot links to an image embedded in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10861852/418556).

Comment: It's a GUI so I guess you cant really copy paste the code?
I'm trying to figure out how i can swap between my Cards on my CardLayouts, nothing really seems to work

Comment: *"It's a GUI so I guess you cant really copy paste the code?"* I have already copy/pasted the code, added `import` statements. Run it & fixed 4 NPEs (I think @Guillaume nailed it here) and then went on to see no effect on pressing any of the buttons. I have debugged thousands of GUIs and posted MCVEs / SSCCEs of many more. So .. yeah of course I ***can.*** But it's going to take an MCVE / SSCCE from you in order for me to put more effort into this..

Comment: BTW - I rejected your suggested edit that added the [tag:windowbuilder] again and destroyed all the edits I had made. I suspect that happened because you hit the 'back' button when trying to make an edit. **Don't do that.** Instead use the little [edit] link below the post. But don't re-add the windowbuilder tag. This has little to do with the IDE and much to do with a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: It would help immensly to know which line of code throws the NPE on your end. And a SSCCE would go a long way in getting an answer here.

Comment: `how i can swap between my Cards on my CardLayouts,` - so why would you create 4 child panels first before doing any testing? The more code you write the harder it is to debug. You should write a little code, then test, then repeat. We are not going to look through 100's of lines of code to spot the 1 line of code that might be wrong. So the solution is start with the working example from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). Modify the code one panel at a time to meet your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

first of all please next time take @AndrewThompson advise about making a MCVE of your code and @camickr advise about the test and debug in little steps before going to the real code (this is the expert programming 101).

the `CardLayout` object switches between the content of the container via the method

```
CardLayout.show(Container parent, String name);
```

keep in mind when making navigation in your swing code DO-NOT make your `Components` fields in a method instead make it local variables (at least in your case the `parentPanel` and the `CardLayout`)

so in order to make your `parentPanel` switch between your 4 panels (sorry am not familiar with your language) i did a fairly refactored version of your code .

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.SystemColor;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    int xx, xy;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Main frame = new Main();
                    frame.setUndecorated(true); // Hides the jframe top bar
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Main() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 735, 506);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBackground(new Color(102, 102, 102));
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JPanel Forside = new JPanel();
        JPanel Dagbog = new JPanel();
        JPanel Aftaler = new JPanel();
        JPanel Kontakt = new JPanel();

        JPanel panelLeft = new JPanel();
        panelLeft.setBackground(new Color(51, 51, 51));
        panelLeft.setForeground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        panelLeft.setBounds(0, 54, 150, 459);
        contentPane.add(panelLeft);
        panelLeft.setLayout(null);

        JButton btnForside = new JButton("Forside");
        btnForside.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                setCardLayoutView("name_1472174211097300");
            }
        });
        btnForside.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        btnForside.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        btnForside.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 17));
        btnForside.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("/Images/icons8_Home_32px_1.png")));
        btnForside.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btnForside.setBorderPainted(false);
        btnForside.setBorder(null);
        btnForside.setBounds(16, 60, 112, 30);
        panelLeft.add(btnForside);

        JButton btnDagbog = new JButton("Dagbog");
        btnDagbog.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setCardLayoutView("name_1472176236196000");
            }
        });
        btnDagbog.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        btnDagbog.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btnDagbog.setBorderPainted(false);
        btnDagbog.setBorder(null);
        btnDagbog.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 17));
        btnDagbog.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        btnDagbog.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("/Images/icons8_Book_32px.png")));
        btnDagbog.setBounds(16, 116, 112, 30);
        panelLeft.add(btnDagbog);

        JButton btnAftaler = new JButton("Aftaler");
        btnAftaler.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setCardLayoutView("name_1472177885026100");
            }
        });
        btnAftaler.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        btnAftaler.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btnAftaler.setBorderPainted(false);
        btnAftaler.setBorder(null);
        btnAftaler.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        btnAftaler.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 17));
        btnAftaler.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("/Images/icons8_Planner_32px.png")));
        btnAftaler.setBounds(16, 173, 112, 30);
        panelLeft.add(btnAftaler);

        JButton btnKontakt = new JButton("Kontakt");
        btnKontakt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setCardLayoutView("name_1472179607862700");
            }
        });
        btnKontakt.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        btnKontakt.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btnKontakt.setBorder(null);
        btnKontakt.setBorderPainted(false);
        btnKontakt.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 17));
        btnKontakt.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        btnKontakt.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("/Images/icons8_Phone_32px.png")));
        btnKontakt.setBounds(16, 231, 112, 30);
        panelLeft.add(btnKontakt);

        JPanel panelTop = new JPanel();
        panelTop.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
                int x = arg0.getXOnScreen(); // makes uggerhøj picture dragable
                int y = arg0.getYOnScreen(); // makes uggerhøj picture dragable
                Main.this.setLocation(x - xx, y - xy);  // makes uggerhøj picture dragable
            }
        });
        panelTop.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                xx = e.getX(); // makes uggerhøj picture dragable
                xy = e.getY(); // makes uggerhøj picture dragable
            }
        });
        panelTop.setBackground(new Color(51, 51, 51));
        panelTop.setBounds(0, 0, 737, 60);
        contentPane.add(panelTop);
        panelTop.setLayout(null);

        JButton btnX = new JButton("X");
        btnX.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        btnX.setRolloverIcon(null);
        btnX.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 18));
        btnX.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        btnX.setFocusPainted(false);
        btnX.setBorderPainted(false);
        btnX.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        btnX.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btnX.setForeground(SystemColor.activeCaption);
        btnX.setBorder(null);
        btnX.setBounds(615, 13, 97, 25);
        panelTop.add(btnX);

        parentPanel = new JPanel();
        parentPanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        parentPanel.setBounds(148, 54, 569, 405);
        contentPane.add(parentPanel);
        cardLayoutObject = new CardLayout(0, 0);
        parentPanel.setLayout(cardLayoutObject);

        parentPanel.add(Forside, "name_1472174211097300");
        Forside.setFocusable(false);

        JButton btnTest = new JButton("test");
        Forside.add(btnTest);

        parentPanel.add(Dagbog, "name_1472176236196000");

        JLabel lblTest = new JLabel("dagbog");
        Dagbog.add(lblTest);

        parentPanel.add(Aftaler, "name_1472177885026100");

        parentPanel.add(Kontakt, "name_1472179607862700");
    }
    private CardLayout cardLayoutObject;
    private JPanel parentPanel;

    private void setCardLayoutView(String viewName) {
        cardLayoutObject.show(parentPanel, viewName);
    }

}
```

and happy coding ^-^.